# Magento 2 Credit memo array get only one item

Tags: magento2, creditmemo

```
public function execute()
{   

    $yourDate = date('2019-11-17');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Collection');
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gt' => $yourDate));

    foreach ($collection as $creditmemo):
    $data = $creditmemo->getData();
    $this->createNewCreditMemoHead($data);
    endforeach;  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked with test order and credit memo with multiple items it's working for me.
Please try this.

```
$yourDate = date('2019-11-21');
    $creditMemoFacory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface');

    $searchCriteria = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
    $searchCriteria = $searchCriteria->addFilter(
        'created_at',
        $yourDate,
        'gt'
    )->create();
    $creditmemos = $creditMemoFacory
    ->getList($searchCriteria)
    ->getItems();
    foreach($creditmemos as $creditMemo){
        foreach($creditMemo->getAllItems() as $items){
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($items->getData());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoRepository::addFieldToFilter() in D:\dev.magento\app\code\Learning\HelloPage\Controller\Page\View.php:201 Stack trace: #0

Comment: sir actually i want all the items from credit memo

Comment: Please check with above code.